# Instantiate base class reference with derived class inside constructor

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have classes A1 and A2 that are derived from class A. 
I have a reference to A class, and I would like to use it's constructor to instantiate the object either by A1 or A2, based on the arguments.

```
class A {
    public A(bool someCondition) {
        if (someCondition) {
            //this = new A1() //this does not work
        } else {
            //this = new A2() //this does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: why not just use a factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Just don't do that inside `A` constructor. You need a static builder method for that:

```
class A {
    public static A build(bool someCondition) {
        if (someCondition) {
            return new A1();
        } else {
            return new A2();
        }
    }
}
```

However doing that inside constructor `A` simply is not possible. Constructor of any particular class is something to which you say: give me instance of this particular class and not other ;-)